# Java Swing: Does the phrase "favor composition over inheritance" apply?

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, composition

Does the phrase "favor composition over inheritance" apply to Swing components? I'd like to gather some professional opinions about the subject and which code is easier to maintain before I go ahead and design a UI.

Comment: Meaning "why did they use so much inheritance"?  History.  Swing was done before "favor" was agreed upon.

Comment: @duffymo, Your understanding of the question is wrong. I'm not talking about how the Swing framework was designed, but about how to design a framework around it.

Comment: OK, then I'd say that composition over inheritance goes double for Swing.  There are few reasons good enough where you need to extend a Swing class.  Composition is all you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does the phrase "favor composition over inheritance" apply to Swing components?

Yes.

The only time I extend a Swing component is when I need to override one or more of the methods.  For instance, I'll extend a JPanel when I want to override the paintComponent method.

All other times, my class will contain the Swing component(s) I need.  This allows me to separate my class methods:

```
frame.getMethod();
```

from the Swing component class methods:

```
frame.getFrame().getPreferredSize();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

**1.** I usually prefer using Composition over Inheritance, **if i do NOT to use all the methods of
   a class or those methods dont apply to my class.**

**2.** Composition works with **HAS-A** relationship..

**eg:**
       Bathroom HAS-A Tub

```
   Bathroom cannot be a Tub
```

**3.** Inheritance is used at its best, **when its used to force some features down to its subclasses.**

eg:

Every Four Wheeler must have Steering, Brakes, Lights, Windows, etc...

Must be able to Accelerate, Apply Brakes, etc....

So its subclasses must have the features that makes it a Four Wheeler.