# JSeparator between BorderLayout.CENTER and BorderLayout.EAST?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I want to make a program with a BorderLayout where the center and the east part is graphically separated. I tried the following, but unfortunately the separator is on the left side of the JFrame and not between the centerPanel and the rightPanel.

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();

centerPanel.add(new JLabel("center"));
rightPanel.add(new JLabel("right"));

getContentPane().add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
getContentPane().add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

getContentPane().add(new JSeparator(JSeparator.VERTICAL), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
```

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [Nested Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/1795530) approach to give your center panel a `BorderLayout` and add the vertical separator to this one instead of the content pane:

```
JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
centerPanel.add(new JLabel("center"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
centerPanel.add(new JSeparator(JSeparator.VERTICAL), BorderLayout.LINE_END);

JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
rightPanel.add(new JLabel("right"));

getContentPane().add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
getContentPane().add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

#### Other notes

1) Since Java 1.4 when using `BorderLayout` the use of new constants is highly encouraged:

```
PAGE_START
PAGE_END
LINE_START
LINE_END
CENTER
```

From [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) tutorial (bold text mine):

> Before JDK release 1.4, the preferred names for the various areas were
>   different, ranging from points of the compass (for example,
>   `BorderLayout.NORTH` for the top area) to wordier versions of the
>   constants we use in our examples. ***The constants our examples use are
>   preferred because they are standard and enable programs to adjust to
>   languages that have different orientations.***

2) Please avoid extending Swing components if you won't add any Swing related feature. See:

- [Extends JFrame vs. creating it inside the the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003802/extends-jframe-vs-creating-it-inside-the-the-program)
- [Java Swing: Does the phrase “favor composition over inheritance”
  apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415813/java-swing-does-the-phrase-favor-composition-over-inheritance-apply)